# Network storage in Docker server

Tags: docker, containers, storage

I have two servers in one switch:
1. Docker server
2. Data storage server

Is it possible store all data from docker containers to data storage server?
Can you recommended me some informations about that? Documentation, manuals.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of is to map your data storage server's drives as network drives to your Docker server. Then simply you can use Docker Volume plugins to map your network drives to your containers.

For more info on how to map a network drive (obviously the instructions will vary depending on your operating system):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/46183/how-to-map-a-network-drive/46185
- http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/

More info on how to use Docker volumes:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume

and finally volume plugins:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/